# Big Data Platform for a healthcare application

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql, bigdata

I have to develop a web application (for Healthcare sector) in python using a Big Data platform (NoSQL Database, like Elasticsearch for ex.)

I want to know, what is the best Big Data platform for this situation ?
Could someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do an evaluation of NoSQL databases. Like write down the features you need or how much you need them, examples how you want to access or fill the database, and then try out several noSQL databases how they perform or how you can work with them.

There is no "best" noSQL Database.